Trying to derive relativistic dispersion formula
If we define conserved quantities of motion as constants arising from continuous symmetries of the system (Lagrangian), why does the following argument not give the correct result?
Let $\gamma: I \to M$ be a geodesic and $\xi$ a Killing vector field. It is well known that the quantity
$$g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t), \xi(\gamma(t)))$$
is conserved along the geodesic.
So in inertial coordinates on Minkowski spacetime, we can write
$$\dot{\gamma}(t) = \frac{dx^i}{d\lambda} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} |{\gamma (t)}$$
And thus for example using the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is a Killing vector field define energy as
$$ E = g_{\gamma(t)}(\frac{dx^i}{d\lambda} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \|{\gamma(t)} , \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |_{\gamma(t)}) $$
Thus $E = -c^2 \frac{dx^0}{d\lambda}$ and the zeroth component of the four velocity may be seen as conserved energy. Doing the above argument for the Killing vector fields $\partial_x \dots \partial_z$ makes the spatial components of the four velocity Newtonian momenta.
This all suggests we have
$$-1 = - E^2/c^2 + |p|^2 $$
or just as well
$$0 = - E^2 /c^2 + |p|^2$$
But where does rest mass enter the picture?
Without Lagrangian mechanics, mass only enters the picture as I've outlined above through $F = ma$ i.e.
$$\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma} = a := \frac{F}{m}$$
What's missing?

You should consult proper textbooks covering the topic of defining energy (or mass) in GR. But a cheap way to see where you are going, is that for massive particles, your identification is actually supposed to be $$\frac Em=-c^2\frac{\mathrm dx^0}{\mathrm d\lambda}$$ and similarly for momentum, so that the correct equation appears.

Good point: I remember the pervasive use of these so called "specific" energy and momenta from analyzing geodesic motion in GR. From a theory standpoint, I bet this mass factor likely follows from Noether's theorem applied to the point particle action.

There is another conserved quantity for any geodesic namely,
$$\mu= -g_{\gamma(\lambda)}(\dot{\gamma}(\lambda), \dot{\gamma}(\lambda))$$
In your argument, you have yet to fix the freedom of changing the affine parameter $\lambda$. Under an affine transformation $\lambda\mapsto \alpha\lambda+\beta$, your constants of motion transform as
\begin{align}
 E &\mapsto \alpha E\\
 \vec{p} &\mapsto \alpha \vec{p}\\
 \mu &\mapsto \alpha^2 \mu.
\end{align}
So up to now you definition of energy and momentum, where ambiguous.
We can choose $\alpha$ such that $E$ and $p$ are equal to the physical energy and momentum of the particle (e.g. defined through ADM integrals at infinity). With choice $\mu$ becomes equal to $m^2$ with $m$ the rest mass, and we get that
$$ - m^2 = -E^2/c^4+ |\vec{p}|^2$$,
as expected. Alternatively, (for timelike geodesics) we can choose $\alpha=1\sqrt{\mu}$ such that $\mu$ becomes 1 and $\lambda$ becomes the proper time. However, with this choice
\begin{align}
 E &\mapsto  E/m\\
 \vec{p} &\mapsto \vec{p}/m,
\end{align}
i.e. your conserved quantities become the specific energy and momentum.
